# What happens if we keep x and y constant and change ϴ and ρ in equation x cos(ϴ) + y sin(ϴ) = ρ?

Tags: geometry

What happens if we keep $x$ and $y$  constant and change $\theta$ and $\rho$ in equation

$$x \cdot cos (\theta) + y \cdot sin (\theta) = \rho$$

?

I know the plot would look like a sine wave.

But, how would be the effect of $x$ and $y$ on the graph? What would be the relationship between (x, y) and the amplitude and phase of the wave?

I have plotted the equation using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%20cos(theta)%20%2B%205%20sin(theta)%20%3D%20rho). The plot doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You'll get a straight line $ax+by=c$ with $a=\cos\theta,b=\sin\theta, c=\rho$.

Comment: @anonymous The WA link you added shows a plot in $\theta, \rho$ with $x=y=5$ constant.

Comment: @anonymous Sorry, demonstrate what? It's not clear what the question is that you mean to ask.

Comment: So again, what is the question? The $\rho$ vs. $\theta$ plot for constant $x,y$ is a sine because of [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin(x)_%2B_b_cos(x)). The $y$ vs. $x$ plot for constant $\theta,\rho$ is a straight line, as pointed out in the very first comment already.

Comment: `that was what I was looking for` Guess that's good, though I don't know what `that` was. You may want to clarify both the title and the body of your question, in particular the `keep θ and ρ constant and change x and y` parts.

Comment: @dxiv, okay. apparently, I wrote incorrect question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\rho=x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigg(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\theta)+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sin(\theta)\bigg)$

Now the amplitude will be $A=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the phase $\phi$ verifies $\begin{cases} \sin(\phi)=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\ \cos(\phi)=\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \end{cases}$

By the sinus addition formula this becomes $\rho=A\sin(\theta+\phi)$.